# Missing data using pyserial on two beaglebone blacks

Tags: python, pyserial, beagleboneblack

I am trying to make two beaglebone microcontrollers to communicate with each other using UART.
When there is an input by user on TX side of microcntroller, RX side has to get that input but my RX side is missing some of the data sent by TX side.

Here is my TX side code

```
import serial
import time

UART.setup("UART1")

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = "/dev/ttyO1",                    #enable UART1
    baudrate = 9600,                    #Set Baudrate = 9600
    )
time.sleep(3)
ser.close()                             #Close serial port
ser.open()                              #Open serial port
ser.flushInput()                        #Flush the input of serial port
ser.flushOutput()                       #Flush the output of serial port
print ser.name                          #Print serial port being used in the beginning

while True:                         #Set the infinite loop for the input
    print('enter the data')
    dataToSend = raw_input()
    tempData = str(dataToSend )
    ser.write(tempData)
```

And this is my RX side code.

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.UART as UART
import serial
import time

UART.setup("UART1")

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = "/dev/ttyO1",                        #enable UART1
    baudrate = 9600                     #Set Baudrate = 9600
    )

time.sleep(3)

ser.close()                             #Close serial port
ser.open()                              #Open serial port
ser.flushInput()                            #Flush the input of serial port
ser.flushOutput()                           #Flush the output of serial port
msg_count = 0
slaveAddress = '1'
addressConfirmed = False

print ser.name                              #Print serial port being used in the beginning

while True: 

    size = ser.inWaiting()

    if size > 0 :
        rawData = ser.read(size)
        rawData = str(rawData)
        print(rawData)


    else:
        pass
```

Can someone please tell me what the problem is with my code?
Thank you

Comment: "RX side is missing some of the data sent by TX side" what exactly?

Comment: when I send a data, it gets the data, and sometimes it doesn't. @AdriánKálazi

Comment: Can you give examples? (e.g. what exactly you transferred) It shouldn't do this randomly.

Comment: @AdriánKálazi Actually, it does that randomly. When I tried to send a string 'asdf(for example)' sometimes it goes, and sometimes RX side doesn't show anything

Comment: What is the ser.read(16384) supposed to do? Have you tried replacing either end with a serial terminal program like minimcom?

Comment: @barny Oh, sorry about confusing you. That was the part of the thing I tried to fix the problem. You can just ignore it

Comment: It affects what you are having problems with. Can i ignore everything else as well? Have you tried minicom. One of the most basic parts of debugging is narrowing down where the problem can be. Eeplacing one end with code you didnt write is a good start

Comment: @barny it was a mixed up with my other version of the code. The code that I tested was without ser.read(16384). I fixed the code that I uploaded. Thanks for the suggestion regarding minicom. I will try

Comment: If it really does it randomly, then it can be pretty much everything, try to place print("x") or something in the if size > 0: block to see if it reaches the inside of the if block. If yes, then it may be problem with reading the data and not with ser.inWaiting()

Comment: In the Rx end you've got ser.read followed by ser.readline. What? That's a recipe for losing the return from ser.read.

Comment: I tested with the minicom and it seems that rx and tx from the microcontrollers look okay. Also I commented ser.readline() out but missing data occasionally still exists. And it reaches to the if block when the condition is satisfied so I guess it might be problem with reading data

Comment: Edit your current, unmodified, without-bits-you-didn't-mean-to-include code into your question.

Comment: How have you connected the two beaglebones together? How many wires, what does each transfer? Have you got a common 0V wire between them?

Comment: @barny Ground was unstable so after I stabilize common ground line, it did not have any missing data from Rx side. So thanks barny.
However, I tried to send a string data from Tx side, Rx only get it as an individual letter. In the other words, when I tried to print the size which I got from inWaiting(), it always returned 1 even when I have a string. Any suggestion?

Comment: At 9600 baud, each character takes about 1 millisecond to send.  Since you're burning 100% CPU time on the receiving end polling for incoming data, you're likely to notice and read that one character before a second character can even be sent.  If you need to receive entire strings, you need to either terminate them with some specific character (commonly a newline), or precede them with a count of characters to follow.

Comment: Yeah, the key fact is not the length of each read, but the totality of what is received. Is that correct?